# Can we create an app that can create popup messages while watching live channel from Google TV

Tags: android, google-tv

Lets say I am developing an app for Google Tv. This app will have a reminder function. While watching live channel from Google TV, can our app display a reminding popup messages right top of the screen? Is that possible?

Comment: It's totally possible, as Les notes, you can use a custom Toast (custom layout/views/colors/duration, etc). It works pretty well, but it's hacky, and it's going to annoy the hell out of people if they are actually watching TV ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can create a longish [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) for [more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html).